# How do I expand the children inside a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I just updated to Fedora 22, and got with it Gnome 3.16.
I'm running a small app of mine and I get a deprecation warning. The xscale property of the Alignment object is going away. There is a problem however, I can not expand the children of a button without it.

I created this simple test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk


class Application(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)
        self.connect('startup', self.on_startup)

    def on_startup(self, app):
        self.window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=app)
        self.window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.MOUSE)
        self.window.set_default_size(600, 200)
        button = Gtk.Button(label='test')
        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file('noimage.png')
        button.set_always_show_image(True)
        button.set_image(image)
        # I can't expand without this property bellow
        button.get_child().set_property('xscale', 1.0)
        self.window.add(button)

    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.window.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app = Application()
    exit_status = main_app.run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(exit_status)
```

You should see a small wide window, with a button in it, covering all of the window's available space. Inside the button you should see an invalid image icon on the left, and a text label on the right.

I separated the image from the label using the xscale property, this expands the size of the Alignment object inside the button and gives more space for the label and image to expand apart. I'd like to know a way to achieve the same result without it.

I used the gtk inspector (Ctrl+Shift+D while the app is running) and tried every sane, and less sane, property in pretty much all objects in that window, with no success. I tried my trusty search engine but couldn't find anyone with such a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkAlignment itself has been deprecated. From [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment.html):

> GtkAlignment has been deprecated in 3.14 and should not be used in newly-written code. The desired effect can be achieved by using the “halign”, “valign” and “margin” properties on the child widget.

There's not much you can do here. The GtkAlignment is an internal child of the GtkButton, and there is code (such as yours) that relies on this structure. If GtkAlignment is ever removed (such as in GTK+ 4), the internal structure of the GtkButton will change too.

If you *really* want to avoid using deprecated functions, you can replace the button's child entirely with a horizontal GtkBox, pack the image and a label inside, and set the image's `hexpand` to `True` to simulate the `xscale` of 1.

Take a look at [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/ch28s02.html) for more information on the new properties.

Comment: Thank you. I just created a Button object without any arguments, I thought it would add an empty label to it by default, but nop. I didn't even need to remove the child from the button. Just created a nice horizontal box like you suggested, added it to the button, and packed the other widgets in the box. It's working like a charm. ^_^